# Since when is capital of a country used to denote government actions?

Tags: history

Nowadays, we commonly use capitals (I refer to the cities) to denote a action taken by a government. e.g.

> "New Delhi decided to pass the food bill."

Here New Delhi refers to the Indian Government.

So since when has this trend started?

Are there any historical examples in literature?

Comment: It has been happening for a long time. See [metonymy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metonymy).

Comment: @MattЭллен also [synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)

Comment: [Wikipedia on metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) contains references to rhetoricians in Ancient Greece and Rome.

Comment: @AndrewLeach so,  Athens originated "metonymy"?  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Andrew Leach indicates in his comment, the use of metonymy goes back to at least Ancient Greece and Rome. This figure of speech included the use of the name of the seat of government to represent the government itself as in this example:

> “The budget should be balanced. Public debt should be reduced. The arrogance of officialdom should be tempered, and assistance to foreign lands should be curtailed, lest **Rome** become bankrupt.”

-*Marcus Tullius Cicero* (Ancient Roman Lawyer, Writer, Scholar, Orator and Statesman, 106 BC-43 BC)

ADDENDUM:

As per outis nihil's comment below, the above is apparently not a real quote from Cicero.

[Another example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est) might be *Furthermore, (moreover) I consider that Carthage must be destroyed*, often shortened to *Carthago delenda est* (*Carthage must be destroyed*). This mantra was oft repeated by Roman orators in the Senate, in particular, Cato the Elder (234-149 BC). The call was to defeat the government of Carthage, not necessarily raze the city itself.

Comment: This is **E** L&U. Cicero didn't write in English in 43 BC. When was metonymy first used in English? (Probably the same question as: when was English first used?)

Comment: @Hugo But Latin and Greek (and several other languages) inform the grammar, vocabulary and figures of speech in English, and the derivations of those elements is of interest to English language aficionados.

Comment: It's a time-honored rhetorical tradition; the OP appears to have finally noticed it and fallen for the [Recency Illusion](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002386.html).

Comment: Note - Bib, this is not a genuine quotation from Cicero; it is, rather, from a novel in which Cicero is a character: Taylor Caldwell's *A Pillar of Iron*. See http://www.snopes.com/quotes/cicero.asp

Comment: @outisnihil Thanks. Most of the online sites have bare quotes without an actual source. Perhaps a better choice would be *Carthage must be destroyed* (Carthago delenda est) a version of which was most likely said by Cato the Elder. The goal was more to bring down the government than to raze the city (although Cato might have welcomed that as well).

Comment: @outisnihil I have added to the answer to reflect your helpful information.

Comment: @bib - No, Cato wanted to **raze the city**. And Rome did just that, and according to legend plowed the area with salt.